# Postfix pop3-ssl connection

Tags: ssl, pop3, postfix-mta

I install mail server with postfix under ubuntu 16.04 lts.
After config pop3-ssl, i have this error when i telnet the server via 995.

```
pop3d-ssl: couriertls: accept: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

this is the config of pop-ssl

```
SSLPORT=995
SSLADDRESS=0
SSLPIDFILE=/var/run/courier/pop3d-ssl.pid
SSLLOGGEROPTS="-name=pop3d-ssl"
POP3DSSLSTART=YES
POP3_STARTTLS=YES
POP3_TLS_REQUIRED=0
COURIERTLS=/usr/bin/couriertls
TLS_STARTTLS_PROTOCOL=TLS1
TLS_KX_LIST=ALL
TLS_COMPRESSION=ALL
TLS_CERTS=X509
TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/ssl/private/vpsabc.example.net.pem
TLS_TRUSTCERTS=/etc/ssl/certs
TLS_VERIFYPEER=NONE
TLS_CACHEFILE=/var/lib/courier/couriersslcache
TLS_CACHESIZE=524288
MAILDIRPATH=Maildir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your server config - telnet is non-SSL-aware, so it won't do a SSL handshake, etc.  You'll need to use sslclient instead to test things running over SSL/TLS.  https://blog.yimingliu.com/2009/01/23/testing-a-pop3-server-via-telnet-or-openssl/